# Como faço para copiar/selecionar uma var no jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou tentando copiar o conteúdo do `var ip`, mas não consigo.

Este é o meu codigo:

```
  $(function(){
    $("#ip-server").click(function(){
      var ip = 'ip.exemplo.com'; /* <-- Esse é o conteudo que quero copiar */
      $('ip').select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
    })
  })
```

Comment: voce quer pegar o valor de um campo com `$('ip').select();` e atribuir usando a outro usando `$("#ip-server").prop(...)`?

Comment: Não, só quero copiar o `var ip`  para clipboard do usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Como precisa copiar o valor da variável `ip` para o clipboard do usuário, imagino que vá precisar de um elemento para acessar o valor pelo jQuery:

```
$("#ip-server").click(function () {
  var ip = 'ip...';
  var $temp = $("<input>"); // cria um elemento temporário
  $("body").append($temp); // insere ele no DOM
  $temp.val(ip); // atribui o valor do IP que deseja a ele
  $temp.select(); // selecione para executar o comando
  document.execCommand("copy"); // copia para o clipboard
  $temp.remove(); // remove o elemento temporário da página
});
```

Caso o elemento `$("#ipserver")` contenha o valor que deseja, pode usar o `$(this).select()` dentro da função click acima ao invés de criar um elemento temporário e removê-lo depois. Isso vai fazer com que o jQuery resgate o valor do elemento atual que recebeu o evento.

Vale ressaltar que da forma que está resgatando o elemento:

```
$('ip')...
```

Indicaria uma tag HTML do tipo `ip`. Se quiser resgatar a partir de uma classe, use o prefixo `.`:

```
$('.ip')...
```

E para IDs:

```
$('#ip')...
```

Há formas mais avançadas de acessar elementos dentro de outros elementos, recomendo pesquisar sobre caso tenha interesse.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.